# Do large bindings inside a Clojure recursive function harm performance?

Tags: performance, recursion, clojure, tail-recursion

I'm writing a function that does a set of transformations based on a declarative set of rules. The rules are a compile-time evaluated collection (no function calls or anything). They will contain hundreds of elements.

The basic layout looks like this:

```
(defn dostuff-with-rules [stuff]
  (let [rules [["foo"] ["bar"] ["baz"] ...]
        transformed (reduce apply-rule stuff rules)]
    (if (not= stuff transformed)
      (recur transformed)
      transformed))))
```

I'm concerned that initializing a large set of data for every function call will harm performance, and it's better to move `rules` outside of the function scope.

Does this make sense, or is Clojure smart enough to just initialize the rules once? Or maybe it makes sense to put a `loop` inside the `let` bindings?

**EDIT:** And what if this is not a simple tail recursion but a tree traversal, with `dostuff-with-rules` recursively called for each node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure (or rather the combination of the compiler and the JVM) is indeed smart enough not to allocate constants repeatedly when looping and recurring so there is little risk of running into problems on that account. If you have an expensive function to initialize the rules and put it inside the loop/fn/recur then it will indeed become a problem though it's easy enough to fix.

here is an example where a vector is recomputed each time:

```
user> (time (loop [a 1]
              (if (< a 4)
                (let [big (vec (range 10e6))]
                  (do (println (rand-nth big))
                      (recur (inc a)))))))
9528975
717854
729682
"Elapsed time: 3753.978349 msecs"
nil
```

and where a constant is referenced:

```
user> (def big (vec (range 10e6)))
#'user/big
user> (time (loop [a 1]
              (if (< a 4)
                (do (println (rand-nth big))
                    (recur (inc a))))))
4002962
7528467
2596236
"Elapsed time: 0.685522 msecs"
nil
```

So if you put your rules in a constant by, for instance loading them from a config file then you will get both the fast performance and a meaningful way to manage them.

It does fail if you try to use too large a literal value (in this case I'm generating it in a macro)

```
user> (defmacro make-big-vec [] (vec (range 10000)))
#'user/make-big-vec
user> (time (loop [a 1]
              (if (< a 4)
                (let [big (make-big-vec)]
                  (do (println (rand-nth big))
                      (recur (inc a)))))))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1716519094506420012.clj:1:7)
```

though 1000 works fine.